# Confused by Chakra Ui semantic tokens top level keys?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm a little confused by the docs on [Semantic Tokens](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/features/semantic-tokens). Lets say we define semantic tokens like this:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  semanticTokens: {
    colors: {
      text: {
        default: "green.500",
        _dark: "blue.500"
      },
      card: {
        default: "gray.50",
        _dark: "gray.700"
      }
    },
    shadows: {
      card: {
        default: "md",
        _dark: "none"
      }
    },
    radii: {
      card: "lg"
    }
  }
});
```

In the example, we're using the categories/top level keys `colors`, `shadows`and `radii`. These seem to be the the top level keys from the `defaultTheme` object. When using the semanticTokens, we do this:

```
<Box shadow="card" p={4} rounded="card" bg="card">
        <Text color="text">Semantic Tokens are Awesome!</Text>
 </Box>
```

Obviously, we did not use `colors.text` but merely `text` to use the token and this seeems to work everywhere a color is expected (e. g. `bg="text"`).

I understand how this works for colors, but what happens if I want to use a semantic token for e.g. `padding="distance-sm"`. What category would I use for this? Do I need the categories (`colors`, `shadows`...) or can I simply omit them? As is, I don't think the docs are very clear on this.

Doing this does not work:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  semanticTokens: {
    distance_sm: 8,
});
```

```
<Box p="distance_sm" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantic tokens are nested mirroring the shape of the theme definition

In the source:

- Semantic Tokens type: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/theme.types.ts#L124
- 'foundations': https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/foundations/index.ts#L13

The following works for me (I've included the other keys in comments for reference):

```js
const theme = extendTheme(
  {
    /** 
     * @see https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/semantic-tokens 
     * @see https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/theme.types.ts#L123
    */
    semanticTokens: {
      // Typography: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/theme.types.ts#L102
      // fonts: {},
      // fontSizes: {},
      // fontWeights: {},
      // letterSpacings: {},
      // lineHeights: {},

      // Foundations: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/src/theme.types.ts#L110
      // borders: {},
      // breakpoints: {},
      // colors: {},
      // radii: {},
      // shadows: {},
      // sizes: {},
      space: {
        distance_sm: 12,
      },
      // transition: {},
      // zIndices: {},
    },
  }
)
```

```
<Box p="distance_sm" />
```

([Chakra v2.2.2](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/theme/package.json#L3))